# Getting the exact count of rows in Postgres database

Tags: postgresql, performance, count, metadata, performance-tuning

Is there any way to get the exact row count of all tables in Postgres in fast way?

`Count(*)` seems to run very slowly for larger tables.

Is there a way to get an exact count from Postgres statistics tables without running vacuum, which is also a costly operation?

Comment: does the count absolutely need to be *exact*, or would a good current estimate be enough if it didn't need a vacuum?

Comment: That should be exact

Answer (score 4):

It seems [there is currently no built-in way](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/985173138.344324.1433950999754.JavaMail.yahoo%40mail.yahoo.com) to do what you require in PostgreSQL.

> People are working toward such capabilities.  While nobody can say
>   with any certainty when such features will make it into a
>   PostgreSQL release, I think it's safe to predict that it will not
>   be before late 2017, and most probably later than that.

Meanwhile, you could manually implement a solution using triggers; for example as described in [Postgresql General Bits](http://www.varlena.com/GeneralBits/120.php) by A. Elein Mustain.

The idea is to maintain an always-current row count in a separate table using triggers. Be aware that this may add significant overhead to data modifications.

Comment: A module that attempts to add more features to materialized views (work still in progress as far as I know): https://github.com/twosigma/postgresql-contrib

Answer (score 2):

You might want to consider using the built-in function **[pgstattuple](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/pgstattuple.html)** which is doucmented as follows:

> The pgstattuple module provides various functions to obtain tuple-level statistics.

***Reference:** [pgstattuple](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/pgstattuple.html) (PostgreSQL Doucmentation)*

You would then simply set off a command like:

```
SELECT * FROM pgstattuple('<schema_name>.<table_name>');
```

...and it will return something similar to this:

```
-[ RECORD 1 ]------+-------
table_len          | 458752
tuple_count        | 1470
tuple_len          | 438896
tuple_percent      | 95.67
dead_tuple_count   | 11
dead_tuple_len     | 3157
dead_tuple_percent | 0.69
free_space         | 8932
free_percent       | 1.95
```

This is similar to using a `SElECT count(*)` as described further down in the page where they recommend using `pgstattuple_approx(regclass)` instead:

> pgstattuple_approx is a faster alternative to pgstattuple that returns approximate results

The explanation for the possible differences being documented as:

> Whereas pgstattuple always performs a full-table scan and returns an exact count of live and dead tuples (and their sizes) and free space, pgstattuple_approx tries to avoid the full-table scan and returns exact dead tuple statistics along with an approximation of the number and size of live tuples and free space.
>
> It does this by skipping pages that have only visible tuples according to the visibility map (if a page has the corresponding VM bit set, then it is assumed to contain no dead tuples). For such pages, it derives the free space value from the free space map, and assumes that the rest of the space on the page is taken up by live tuples.
>
> For pages that cannot be skipped, it scans each tuple, recording its presence and size in the appropriate counters, and adding up the free space on the page. At the end, it estimates the total number of live tuples based on the number of pages and tuples scanned (in the same way that VACUUM estimates pg_class.reltuples).

Possible example:

```
SELECT * FROM pgstattuple_approx('<schema_name>.<table_name>::regclass);
```

Possible results:

```
-[ RECORD 1 ]--------+-------
table_len            | 573440
scanned_percent      | 2
approx_tuple_count   | 2740
approx_tuple_len     | 561210
approx_tuple_percent | 97.87
dead_tuple_count     | 0
dead_tuple_len       | 0
dead_tuple_percent   | 0
approx_free_space    | 11996
approx_free_percent  | 2.09
```

Comment: again we say if we want to get exact count, we need to use 'pgstattuple', which is like count(*) right

Comment: Yes, the mechanism is the same. However, seeing as _pgstattuple acquires only a read lock on the relation. So the results do not reflect an instantaneous snapshot; concurrent updates will affect them._ it could be a fraction faster than a simple `count(*)`. This is something you would have to test against your large table.